# org-super-agenda - Item Isn't Added to Agenda But can be Found Using org-ql

Tags: org-mode

I am using Emacs 28.2 with Spacemacs. I've been a happy `org-super-agenda` user for a few years now but I haven't really made many changes.

Recently I wanted to start tracking todo's with new keywords, like this:

```
* Tasks
** TODAY Go grocery shopping
** LATER Buy new toaster
** SOMEDAY Fix the blender
```

I therefore configured my `org-super-agenda` as so:

```
(setq org-super-agenda-groups
      '((:log t)                     ; Automatically named "Log"
        (:name "Schedule"
               :time-grid t)
        (:name "Today"  ;; ***implicit OR***
               :scheduled today
               :todo "TODAY")
        (:name "Later"
               :tag "LATER")
        (:name "Unimportant"
               :todo ("SOMEDAY" "MAYBE" "CHECK" "TO-READ" "TO-WATCH")
               :order 100)
        (:habit t)
        (:name "Due today"
               :deadline today)
        (:name "Overdue"
               :deadline past)
        (:name "Due soon"
               :deadline future)
        (:name "Waiting..."
               :todo "WAITING"
               :order 98)
        (:name "Scheduled earlier"
               :scheduled past))
      org-agenda-prefix-format
      '((agenda . " %i %-12:c%?-12t%-6e% s")
        (todo . " %i %-12:c")
        (tags . " %i %-12:c")
        (search . " %i %-12:c")))

(setq org-agenda-span 1)
(setq org-agenda-start-day "today")

(org-super-agenda-mode)
```

I then added a task to one of my agenda files with a 'SOMEDAY' keyword but it will not appear in my agenda.

I then tested it with an `orq-ql-search` query of my agenda files and was able to find the heading.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

**Update**: I also have the following header at the top of my Agenda file:

- `#+TODO: TODO(t) TODAY(y) LATER(l) SOMEDAY(s) WAIT(w@) | DONE(d) CANCELED(c)`

So all of the necessary phases should be recognized I believe.

The file is part of my agenda file list. The SOMEDAY task is **not** timestamped.

Comment: You probably need to make your keywords known to Org mode by customizing `org-todo-keywords` (or by adding `#+TODO: ...` to your file).

Comment: Thank you @NickD - Here's what I currently have at the top of my inbox.org file where these tasks exist: `#+TODO: TODO(t) TODAY(y) LATER(l) SOMEDAY(s) WAIT(w@) | DONE(d) CANCELED(c)`. Is there a different way I should do it?

Comment: No, that should be enough to let Org mode know what the keywords are. Can you please add this information to your question? The question needs to stand on its own, even if the comments disappear. Next question: is the task you added timestamped/scheduled/deadlined within the date range of the chosen agenda? I presume your inbox.org file is the agenda file where you added the task?

Comment: Thank you @NickD for the suggestions! I added the answers to your questions to the question.

Comment: If the task is not timestamped, it's not going to appear in the daily/weekly/monthly agenda: only tasks with timestamps that match a date within the range of the agenda appear there. So if you do `C-c a a` (assuming you use the suggested keybinding to `org-agenda`), the task will not appear. OTOH, if you do `C-c a t`, the task *should* appear: that's the TODO agenda view.